# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'RxList<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

[image]

i'm Getting Type issue i dont what i did wrong, i'm trying to store data in GetX controller class and make it observable.

my code : -

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../Services/HttpService.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class SelectedCardController extends GetxController{

var selectedProductList = List().obs;

@override
void onInit() async{
super.onInit();
getProductDetail();
}


selectedProduct() async {
try {
  HttpService httpService = HttpService();
  var response = await httpService.get('business', 'product', 'get', '6035de62bf7db17c5dfd9977');
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> decodedResponse = json.decode(response);
  print('res -----------------  $decodedResponse');
  print(selectedProductList.runtimeType);
if (decodedResponse['code'] == 200) selectedProductList = decodedResponse['content'];
  print("result ------ $selectedProductList");
} 
catch (e) {print(e);} 
}
```

Thanks for your help in Advance

Comment: i think it's because you are trying to assign `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>` to `RxList<dynamic>`.

try `if (decodedResponse['code'] == 200) selectedProductList = RxList.from(decodedResponse['content']);`

Comment: bro after trying that im getting this : type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're trying to use a list to convert the raw JSON data but you should use a map instead. My advice is that you should first create a model in order to convert the JSON data to an instance of that model. Check out the Flutter docs for reference: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing#create-a-photo-class

There's a very nice tool that helps you automating the model creation, just paste the JSON data and it'll generate the correct model for you: https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

However, if you're still learning, I would recommend you to try creating the model manually for now, it's good for practice.

Once you do that, you can simply replace `var selectedProductList = decodedResponse['content'];` with `Content selectedProductList = Content.fromJson(decodedResponse['content']);`

If you still get a similar error message, you can also try `Content selectedProductList = Content.fromJson(Map.from(decodedResponse['content']));`

Comment: thanks for help brother but i was told to do this without using any model that's why i chose this approach

Answer (score 0):

change the following line:

```
 Map<dynamic, dynamic> decodedResponse = json.decode(response);
```

to this:

```
 Map<String, dynamic> decodedResponse = json.decode(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

finally it worked - thanks for everyone who spend time on this issue

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../Services/HttpService.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class SelectedCardController extends GetxController{

var selectedProductList = Map().obs;

@override
void onInit() async{
super.onInit();
getProductDetail();
}


  getProductDetail() async {
 try {
  HttpService httpService = HttpService();
  var response = await httpService.get('business', 'product','get',
  '6035de62bf7db17c5dfd9977');
  Map<String, dynamic> decodedResponse = json.decode(response);
  if (decodedResponse['code'] == 200) selectedProductList.value = 
 decodedResponse['content'] ;
  print("sdbcdbck--------------$selectedProductList");
 } 
 catch (e) {print(e);} 
 }
```